# When using UnityContainer.Resolve all references on a db.entity is loaded

Tags: c#, unity-container

I'm using *UnityContainer* to Intercept different method calls in order to do some logging to a database. In relation to this I have to following method for resolving a container.

```
        private TInterface ResolveContainer<TInterface, TConcrete>(TInterface field) where TConcrete : TInterface
    {

        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
        container.RegisterInstance(field);
        container.RegisterType<TInterface, TConcrete>(
            new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>());
        container.RegisterType<TInterface, TConcrete>(
                            new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(),
                            new InterceptionBehavior<LogInterceptor>());
        var resolvedField = container.Resolve<TInterface>();
        return resolvedField;
    }
```

Suppose now that i have a class *Student* that for simplicity could look like this:

```
    public class Student : IStudent
{
    public DbHandler Dbh { get; }
    public FlexDbContext Db { get; set; }
    public Student(DbHandler dbh, FlexDbContext db)
    {
        Dbh = dbh;
        Db = db;
    }

    public StudentSet GetStudent(Guid studentId)
    {
        var student = Db.Students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == studentId);
        return student;
    }
}
```

Furthermore assume that StudentSet hold references to different teachers and fellow students (classmates), which we have no interest in getting references to when we use the *GetStudents* method, hence we want to lazyload. On my dbHandler i have a property that takes a instance of the student class and makes a call to *Resolve Container* as follows:

```
       public IStudent Student
    {
        get
        {
            return ResolveContainer<IStudent, Student(_student);
        }
    }
```

However if i now try to get a student then the student object contains references to teachers and classmates which it should not:

```
        var dbhandler = new DbHandler();
        var foo = dbhandler.Student.GetStudent(new Guid("a15a743e-df6a-j711-b7cd-42152975e16c"));
        dbhandler.SetLazyLoading(false);
```

After some debugging i found that if i replace the *ResolveContainer* method with the following method for setting up my interception then the student object did not contain references to teachers and classmates as is the intended behaviour:

```
    public static IStudent GetClassToInterceptInterface(Student field)
    {
        //IClassToIntercept ReturnClass = new ClassToIntercept();
        IStudent returnClass = Intercept.ThroughProxy<IStudent>(field, new TransparentProxyInterceptor(), new IInterceptionBehavior[]
        {
            new LogInterceptor()
        });
        return returnClass;
    }
```

So here is my question or concerns:

1) How can I use UnityContainer with code first Lazy loading so that my studentSet object does not contain references to teachers and students. Please note that I have tried to use Lazy and Func as explained in: [Deferring the Resolution of Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507482(v=pandp.30).aspx), but without any success.

2) Is there any performance issues using *Intercept.ThroughProxy* especially since it is no longer being maintained.

Please let me know if you have any follow up questions or other concerns

Comment: If you use `Intercept.ThroughProxy` with an `InterfaceInterceptor` instead of `TransparentProxyInterceptor` do you see any behavior changes? That's a more apples to apples comparison. I think the stand-alone interception of `Intercept.ThroughProxy` should use the same interception approach as the container returning a proxy object. Based on the posted code it seems as though you are not using any features of the container besides interception so the stand-alone approach makes sense (assuming that you are OK using Unity since it is not currently being actively maintained).

Comment: @RandyLevy Thanks for your reply, Randy. As for the references i do not see a change in behavior  and will for now therefor stick with `Intercept.ThroughProxy`, however I will probably change to _PostSharp_ as the transition does not seem to be to complicated and it seems to work wonderfull with log4net. Again, thank you

Comment: @RandyLevybtw you should not happen to know any alternatives to _unity_ that support interception?

Comment: I think most do. 
 For example, https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/InterceptionExtensions.html, https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/interceptors.md